# How do I handle multiple quotes in an alias (for bash or zsh)

Tags: bash, shell, python, zsh, alias

I am using zsh, and I am trying to use python as a simple calculator. I'm very familiar with python, but can't seem to get the alias (or function) to work properly.

So far I've got:

```
pycalc() {
  python -c "print '$@'"
}
alias p=pycalc
```

No matter what I do, it returns `zsh: no matches found: 123*123` (123*123 being the math problem).

Any ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bash**
Add the following to .bashrc

```
pycalc() {
  python -c "print \"%f\" % float($@)"
}
alias p=pycalc
```

You can append it with the echo command.
One-line:

```
echo -e 'pycalc() {\n  python -c \"print \\\"%f\\\" % float($@)\"\n}\nalias p=pycalc' >> .bashrc
```

Multi-line:

```
echo -e 'pycalc() {
  python -c \"print \\\"%f\\\" % float($@)\"
}
alias p=pycalc' >> .bashrc
```

You can now use p

```
$ pycalc 12+12
24.000000
$ pycalc 12*12
144.000000
$ p 12+12
24.000000
$ p 12*12
144.000000
```

As Michael Righi noted in his answer, if you have file like 12*12, it will be matched by the 12*12 so you may want to enclose it in double quotes. You can also enclose it in single quotes. His solution works for bash too.

Comment: I'm still getting `zsh: no matches found: 2*2` when i enter `p 2*2`

I'm using zsh by the way, but I don't think that should make much of a difference.

Comment: Is `pycalc 2*2` working? You added the modifications to .zshrc instead of .bashrc, right?

Comment: Did you reinitialize the terminal with the `reset` command so that the new .bashrc can be read?

Comment: @BobJ `reset` has nothing to do with reloading `~/.bashrc`. It is neither a prerequisite for it nor does it actively reload ~/.bashrc. If you want to load new settings from `~/.bashrc` just call `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Works!!!! yeah I did add it to zshrc instead of bashrc. i ran zsh again and it works!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**zsh**

Add this to .zshrc:

```
pycalc() {
  python -c "print $@"
}
alias p=pycalc
```

In your Z shell, use it like this:

```
$ p 12+12
24
$ p "12*12"
144
```

Notice you need the double quotes when the statement contains a globbing character such as the asterisk.

Or, you could turn off globbing for that alias:

```
pycalc() {
  python -c "print $@"
}
alias p='noglob pycalc'
```

That eliminates the need for the double quotes when you use it:

```
$ p 12+12
24
$ p 12*12
144
```